# How to set key validated time in c#

Tags: c#

I'm generating key using c# and send it among the user by mail. This part I was able to do.
I want to set key validated time. When the key validate time is expire it not work. How can I do this?

Key Generate and send it by mail

```
    public IHttpActionResult SendMail()
    {
        string mailBodyhtml = KeyGenerator.GetUniqueKey();
        var msg = new MailMessage("from@gmail.com", "to1@gmail.com", "Hello", mailBodyhtml);
        msg.To.Add("tomail@gmail.com");
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); //if your from email address is "from@hotmail.com" then host should be "smtp.hotmail.com"**
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@gmail.com", "#######");
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Send(msg);
        Console.WriteLine("Email Sended Successfully");
        return Ok("Send Mail");
    }


public class KeyGenerator
{
    public static string GetUniqueKey()
    {
        int size = 6;
        char[] chars =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".ToCharArray();
        byte[] data = new byte[size];
        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            crypto.GetBytes(data);
        }
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size);
        foreach (byte b in data)
        {
            result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe not just send it, but store as well, along with expiry date?

Comment: probably you want to handle this when the user tries to use that key they got?
maybe this is better to handle at activation time?

Comment: I can store it but how to set up expire time?

Comment: you can store key and  `DateTime` wherever you're storing and then check them by using `DateTime.Compare(stored, UserAccessTime)`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're not familiar with `DateTime` in `c#`, It should be enough to achieve what you are willing to get.

First we're generating a key and storing ExpDate and Key,

```
public class KeyGenerator
        {
            public static string GetUniqueKey()
            {
                int size = 6;
                char[] chars =
                    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890".ToCharArray();
                byte[] data = new byte[size];
                using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider crypto = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    crypto.GetBytes(data);
                }

                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(size);
                foreach (byte b in data)
                {
                    result.Append(chars[b % (chars.Length)]);
                }

                var ExpiryDate = DateTime.Now;
                // before returning store it to somewhere along with user unique id to verify later.. 
                // maybe user id is string 
                return result.ToString();
            }

            public static bool IsValidKey(string UserId)
            {
                // first get the Key and saved DateTime..
                // lets assume ExpDate is DateTime object that was saved..
                var Now = DateTime.Now;
                if (DateTime.Compare(Now, ExpDate) <= 0)
                {
                    // Now is earlier or exact ExpDate, we've saved earlier
                    // key is still valid 
                    // handle this scenario 
                   return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Then just verifying that case, that's all!

Here goes the docs: [DateTime.Compare(DateTime, DateTime) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 0):

Okay there could be two way one is you should store the expiry time and key. So you could validate every key accordingly. Second option in you should embed the expiry date time with the key and send the key.